# Pass parameter from a text field contained in another form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

I have two forms in a JSP page, one contains a text field. I need to make sure that whenever the other form is submitted, it copies the value contained in that text field, and writes it's text value in an hidden parameter.

More clearly:

1. One form is named "search";
2. Another form is named "changeInitialForm";
3. The text field is contained in the "search" form, and it's name is "searchString";
4. The "changeInitialForm" has an hidden field, also this named "searchString";
5. The purpose is to make sure that whether the user submits one or another form, a "searchString" parameter is passed, with the value of the text field.

I tried to include an action in javascript, executed when the "changeInitialForm" is submitted, that reads the text field value and writes it into the hidden parameter:

```
function searchContacts(form)
{
    var searchString= document.search.searchString.value;
    form.searchString.value= searchString;
}

...

<form name="search" >
    <input type="text" name="searchString">
    <button name="search"> Cerca </button>
</form>

...


<form name="changeInitialForm" method="post" action="AddressBookView.jsp" onSubmit="searchContacts(this.form);">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedInitial"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="view"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="searchString" />
</form>
```

But after the "changeInitialForm" is submitted, regardless of the text field value, and empty parameter is passed, I am seeing this with firebug:

[image]

I would also appreciate an alternative solution, because I know what I am doing is tricky, but I don't find another method to do that. "search" and "changeInitialForm" cannot be joined in a single form, because they do very different things.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? or just native JavaScript?

Comment: where is the submit button?

Comment: It appears that when you click the `search` button, you are trying to submit the `.changeInitialForm` form.  However, what about the `search` form, which does not show a method or action or any JavaScript method?  You can't submit two forms at the same time unless you use AJAX, which implies a much more complicated problem than you might be expecting.

Comment: I am not using jquery. As for why the form doesn't have a submit button, the answer is that I am submitting the form through a javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work

```
function searchContacts(form)
{
    var searchString= document.search.searchString.value;
    form.searchString.value= searchString;
}

...

    Form 1:
<form name="search" >
    <input type="text" name="searchString">
    <button name="search"> Cerca </button>
</form>

...

    Form 2:
<form name="changeInitialForm" method="post" action="AddressBookView.jsp" onSubmit="searchContacts(this);">
    <input type="hidden" name="selectedInitial"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="view"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="searchString" />
</form>
```

Notice that `searchContacts(this.form)` was replaced with `searchContacts(this)`.

**UPDATE** after some precisions by the author of the question:

The `onsubmit` event is not triggered when `form.submit()` is called by some javascript code. Thus, what you need when you submit the form is to call `searchContacts` separately, for example using

```
searchContacts(document.changeInitialForm);
document.changeInitialForm.submit();
```

Comment: It didn't work for me, the parameter is still an empty string. I don't need the submit button because I am submitting the form with javascript code.

Comment: I just updated my solution according to the precision you just gave.